# How can I redirect ant exec task output to both a file and stdout?

Tags: ant

I am using the [ant (1.8.2) exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) to start a child process. I need the output of the child process to be shown as part of the normal ant console output, but also be captured in a file.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need the [redirector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/redirector.html)

Since Ant 1.6.3 it has an option called `alwayslog`.

Use it like this:

```
<exec executable="mycommand">
   <redirector output="myfile.txt" alwayslog="true"/>           
</exec>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. You saved me from having to deal with the complexities of forking the shell, running the command and piping the output.