# Ant shell command and outputting to file

Tags: shell, ant, awk

I have an Ant build that launches the AWK command. It works except it outputs the result to screen as oppose to saving to a file.

```
<exec executable="awk">
        <arg value="-f" />
        <arg value="shell.sh" />
        <arg value="${SOURCE_DIR}/source.php" />
        <arg value="${BUILD_DIR}/destination.php" />
    </exec>
```

So it's the last argument line that doesn't seem to work:

```
<arg value="${BUILD_DIR}/destination.php" />
```

I'm probably not doing this correctly. Can someone tell me what I need correct in the above example to output to a file?

Comment: To save to a file you can `command > file`.

Comment: @fedorqui - Yes, I know. My command works when I'm in the terminal but I need to know the syntax in my Ant build file.

Comment: It can bee like: `<redirector output="myfile.txt" alwayslog="true"/>   ` from what I see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500187/how-can-i-redirect-ant-exec-task-output-to-both-a-file-and-stdout

Comment: @fedorqui - That works actually. Thanks for the help. If you post as an answer, I'll accept it...

Comment: out of curiosity, what is it you're trying to do?  it's likely you can do it in ant without execing out to awk.

Comment: @Andrew: The answer was post but it seems you forgot to upvote and/or accept it.